# this.http.get return not found just on app module

Tags: angularjs, typescript, promise, rxjs, angular2-routing

On Angular 11, I am calling an endpoint in my service

```
  getServerTime() {
return this.http.get(environment.api.serverTime);
```

}
injecting above service into  app.component

```
this.serviceA.getServerTime().subscribe((serverTime: any) => {
  this.offset = new Date().getTime() - serverTime;
});
```

thorws

> }
> ​
> message: "
> Http failure response for https://url/ntp: 500 undefined

however if i put all the code in a component that has been lazy loaded and call it from ngOnInt then it works fine.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: also the response do come back if i check the network tab but throws the error regardless

Answer (score 0):

https://url/ntp: 500 undefined

500 undefined error code is likely the server has an issue. If this were a wrong API endpoint, the expected return code would be 404. If this were an authorization issue, the return code would be 401. 500 error suggests the correct API endpoint was called but an error occurred while trying to service your request. I would recommend calling the API using PostMan, Fiddler, or your web browser and debugging your API endpoint to verify it can handle your request as expected. Once the API is working as expected, try your front-end application once more.